# react-input-mask customization when user doesn't type 0's

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use [react-input-mask]
with a mask of

```
<InputMask mask='99/99/99' maskChar=''/>
```

This works great if a user types in `02/21/18`
but if a user types in `2/9/18` then they get `29/18/` which is not very intuitive.

I'd like for them to get `02/09/18` added for them. Does anyone know if there is a way for me to achieve this. If not maybe someone could point me in the right direction to a possible solution to writing it myself?

Comment: How is it supposed to know that it's `1/1/18` and not `11/18/..`?

Comment: Good point but  there isn't 18 months in the year.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `beforeMaskedValueChange` to append leading zero conditionally on input length. Of course it should be removed when a user enters 6 numbers.

Comment: can you please give an example of how we can do this?